# C Server http response . Body not parsed

Tags: c, http

i encounter another problem writing a C HTTP Server. When i answer clients with a http response, it seems that i have a bug somewhere but i cant figure out where exactly.

My response headers look like this:

```
"HTTP1/1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 74\r\n\r\n{\"success\":true,\"user_info\":[{\"id\":\"64\"},{\"udid\":\"0\"},{\"profile_id\":\"0\"}]}\n"
```

It seems ok with me, but somehow firefox is not parsing the JSON content and printing it out. It works fine on Chrome and Safari. Also when i do a XMLHTTPResponse to my server, the body doesnt get extracted from the headers.

This is how i write the response:

```
void
mx_respond_json(struct connection_s* connection, struct event_handler_s* handler, const char* data)
{
  struct write_buffer_s* wb = malloc(sizeof(struct write_buffer_s));
  eh_write_buffer_init(wb, 512 + strlen(data) + 1, handler, &connection);

 char len_buf[10];
 memset(len_buf, 0, sizeof(len_buf));
 sprintf(len_buf, "%d", strlen(data));

 strcpy(wp->buffer, "HTTP1/1 200 OK\r\n"
                               "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n"
                               "Connection: close\r\n"
                               "Content-Length: ");
 strcat(wb->buffer, len_buf);
 strcat(wb->buffer, "\r\n\r\n");
 strcat(wb->buffer, data);
 strcat(wb->buffer, "\n");

 eh_write(wb, strlen(wb->buffer), &eh_close);
 }
```

eh_close is the callback which gets called when write finishes and closes the connection to the client.

I also found out that the clientw ill never receive data when i dont close the connection. Maybe this is the reason why there is something wrong?

Greetings.
Markus

Comment: Shouldn't the header start with `"HTTP/1.1"`?

Comment: The first `strcpy()` call uses `wp` instead of `wb`, typo?

Comment: you can look at what firefox sees with firebug. in the Net tab, you have headers and body as firefox understood them. do you have a public URL to test it?